# Location of AngularJS views within Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, angularjs

I'm trying to integrate AngularJS within a Rails app. I have a Rails app with a books controller and book model. In the Rails index view I have this, and AngularJS should take over from here:

```
.page_text{"ng-app" => "books"}
  .row
    .twelve.columns
      %div{"ng-view" => ""}
```

And the AngularJS controller looks like this:

```
function BooksOverviewCtrl($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('/books.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.books = data;
  });
}
BooksOverviewCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$http'];
```

And this is the routeProvider:

```
angular.module('books', []).
  config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
      when('/books', { templateUrl: 'books/book-overview.html.haml',   controller: BooksOverviewCtrl });
}]);
```

Currently, the AngularJS view is in "app/assets/javascripts/angularjs/books/book-overview.html.haml". When I load the page, it says page not found, so where do I have to store the AngularJS views in my Rails app? This is the error:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/books/book-overview.html.haml 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After some researching, I found there are two ways to deal with this. The first option is the way both Mahbub and Adnan Doric mention: store the files in the public folder because they are staic html files anyway.

Although this works it feels not natural for me, because then the files get scattered. Some are in the public folder, and others are in the assets/javascripts folder. Not my preferred option, but it might work well for other people.

The second option is to store the routes in a specific file, like "assets/javascripts/routes.js.erb". Because of the ".erb" it is possible to use the Rails asset_path within the file and create a relative path like this:

```
when('/books', { templateUrl: "<%= asset_path('book-overview.html.haml') %>",   controller: BooksOverviewCtrl });
```

Maybe not the perfect solution, but for me this works best, because now all my Angular files are kept together within the "assets/javascripts" folder.

Comment: Although this method will get you up and running, it causes a server round-trip. Solutions are discussed here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/V3hMGIDwE3o

Comment: But then where do you store book-overview.html.haml? I tested this method with a view from app/views, and got a 404.

Comment: if it's true that this causes a server round trip.. then it pretty much defeats the purpose of having a single page web app which is one of the main pluses of frameworks like angular

Answer (score 21):

I use the [$templateCache](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$templateCache) to handle this. So in the view I have:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="bookOverview.html">
  <%= render partial: "book-overview" %>
</script>
```

Then with $routeProvider you can just:

```
$routeProvider
  .when('/books', {
    templateUrl: 'bookOverview.html',
    controller: BooksOverviewCtrl 
  });
```

This way you can just keep your views in the `app/views/books` directory where you would normally keep them.

Comment: Just one addition i took me time to figure out. The <script type="text/ng-template"> is placed in parent view of the page so it is  rendered at page load.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the [angular-rails-templates](https://github.com/pitr/angular-rails-templates) gem you can get them into the rails asset pipeline and use the [template cache](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24templateCache) from angular.

Links:

- [angular-rails-templates](https://github.com/pitr/angular-rails-templates)
- [template cache](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24templateCache)

Answer (score 2):

You put AngularJS partials in public folder WITHOUT disabling the asset pipeline, just make sure it is accessible in your browser at the specified URL.

Answer (score 1):

I created a new folder in the App/Assets/Javascript called Angular. The Angular folder contains sub-folder for controllers, views, services and directives.

Now to reference a view, lets say sample.html. This is what my templateUrl path looked like.

.when('/sample', {
        templateUrl: '/assets/angular/views/sample.html',
        controller: 'SampleCtrl'
      })

This way All the Angular code **resides in one single folder** and is not scattered all over the place. 
Also, the **Rails Asset Pipeline** can be leveraged for minification and compression of Angular's Controllers and Services.

Answer (score 1):

I also suggest using **Angular Rails Templates**

## Gemfile

`gem 'angular-rails-templates'`

`$ bundle install`

## application.js

`//= require angular-rails-templates`

## app.js

`angular.module('myApp', ['templates'])`

Now, when you include `templateUrl: 'books/book-overview.html.haml'` it will search through your assets folder for the correct view.

Answer (score 0):

I've turned the asset pipeline off in config/application.rb and put all the files in public folder. Since the client side files (angularJS project) don't need any processing, filters, i chose that way.

Answer (score 0):

The following might be good if you want to keep the two separated completely.

One option might be to create a file system symbolic link between the `/ngapp/dist` or `/ngapp/build` folder and the `/public` folder or a subfolder within `/public`. Use a grunt/node server to develop and test in, so you don't have to rebuild each time, and then `grunt build` to the linked `/ngapp/dist` folder when you are ready to push to your remote server.

This keeps the AngularJS folder separate from the Rails app, but allows access only to the final build files, not the source files within your AngularJS app folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use gem [`js_assets`](https://github.com/kavkaz/js_assets)

#### Slim for AngularJS

For example we want to use templating Slim in AngularJS app. Let our templates will be in `app/assets/webapp/`. We make the following settings:

```
# config/application.rb
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'webapp')

# config/initizlizers/assets_engine.rb
Rails.application.assets.register_engine('.slim', Slim::Template)

# config/environments/production.rb
config.assets.precompile += ['*.html']
```

Do not forget to connect a file in your `application.js`

```
//= require app_assets
```

Now for the template `app/assets/webapp/blogs/edit.html.slim` we can get a path depending on the environment:

```
var path = asset_path('blogs/edit.html')

// the function will return for development:
// /assets/blogs/edit.html

// and for production
// /assets/blogs/edit-5eb3bb250d5300736006c8944e436e3f.html

$routeProvider
    .when('/books', {
    templateUrl: assetPath('bookOverview.html'),
    controller: BooksOverviewCtrl 
});
```